# Multiple Redis instances on Yosemite

Tags: macos, redis, osx-yosemite

I am trying to install multiple Redis services in osx 10.10.2 Yosemite. I am trying to do this manually avoiding brew

first I installed redis

```
$ cd ~
$ wget http://redis.googlecode.com/files/redis-2.4.19.tar.gz
$ tar xzf redis-2.4.17.tar.gz
$ cd redis-2.4.17
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Then I copied two config files

```
$ cat redis.conf > /usr/local/etc/redis-6379.conf
$ cat redis.conf > /usr/local/etc/redis-6380.conf
```

and I edited those files changing the following lines with the correspondig number

for redis-6379.conf

```
daemonize yes
pidfile /usr/local/var/run/redis-6379.pid
port 6379
logfile "/usr/local/var/log/redis-6379.log"
dbfilename dump-6379.rdb
```

for redis-6380.conf

```
daemonize yes
pidfile /usr/local/var/run/redis-6380.pid
port 6380
logfile "/usr/local/var/log/redis-6380.log"
dbfilename dump-6380.rdb
```

Then I edited services for both instances

```
$ sudo vi /Library/LaunchDaemons/io.redis.redis-server-6379.plist

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>io.redis.redis-server-6379</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/local/bin/redis-server</string>
      <string>/usr/local/etc/redis-6379.conf</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</plist>

$ sudo vi /Library/LaunchDaemons/io.redis.redis-server-6380.plist

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
  <plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>io.redis.redis-server-6380</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/local/bin/redis-server</string>
      <string>/usr/local/etc/redis-6380.conf</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Then I registered both services

```
$ sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/io.redis.redis-server-6379.plist
$ sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/io.redis.redis-server-6380.plist
```

Finally I tried to restart them

```
$ sudo launchctl start io.redis.redis-server-6379
$ sudo launchctl start io.redis.redis-server-6380
```

But neither of both is working. I am thinking that maybe I have to create some files and folders manually to make this work. But which permissions should I grant to this files and folders?

Or maybe is another mistake

Thank you

Comment: Sorry, my bad, seems is working, I left this here if it is useful for someone else.